# How to deal with JavaCPP avoiding data copy?

Tags: java, android, memory, java-native-interface, javacpp

I'm using JavaCPP to exploit some C++ libraries in a Java application but manipulated datas are big datas. So my code works fine but is not memory-friendly (and I need it to work fast):

- I have a big `byte[][]` to provide to the native part.
- Target native function is something like `nativeFunction(PointerPointer param)` -> [Doc](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/PointerPointer.html)
- (To be precise, this is a `PointerPointer<BytePointer>` type expected, so a list of `BytePointer` as `byte[][]` is a list of `byte[]`) -> [Doc](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/BytePointer.html)

I initialize the expected param this way:

```
byte[][] myBigDatas;
// myBigDatas.length = 4
// myBigDatas[x].length = something like 4000000

// Initialize param
PointerPointer<BytePointer> srcParam = new PointerPointer<BytePointer>(
    myBigDatas[0],
    myBigDatas[1],
    myBigDatas[2],
    myBigDatas[3]);

// Call the native function
nativeFunction(srcParam);
```

Problem is, referring to documentation, for each `BytePointer` created by the call of `PointerPointer<BytePointer>(...)` with provided data, it's not a memory wrapping, but a copy that is made.

There is a way to avoid copy ?

EDIT:

Otherwise, does JNI provide solution for give AND return `byte[][]` **WITHOUT COPYING IT**? (I know it is for a simple `byte[]`)

Comment: If memory and execution time are critical and native cannot be avoided, I'd shift more code to native side ...

Comment: @Fildor is right. I suggest that read the byte[] in c++ instead of java.

Comment: @Both-of-you Of course you're right but unfortunately, I can't for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, and just want to share it. I replaced my `byte[][]` with a `ByteBuffer[]` (an array of **direct** `ByteBuffer`). Then, doing

```
BytePointer bp = new BytePointer(/*direct ByteBuffer*/)
```

doesn't make copy! Performance gain is huge!!